# GWT - How to go from UI to Java Implementation

Tags: java, gwt

I'm wondering if there is a strategy for identifying the Java under workings of the UI contents on a webpage of a GWT application.

For example, I have a webpage which has a left panel with different tabs, and when I click on each tab the UI changes bringing forth different contents that are coming from a database.  I'm assuming this is using some sort of service and DAO, but not really sure how to trace back through the code to get to that point.

I'm coming from Spring MVC where I can use the URL to identify a Controller which will then direct me to the right place. Is there anything like this for GWT?

Thanks!

Comment: GWT makes RPC calls to servlet. The quick way will be to use a firefox plugin like FireBug or LiveHttpHeaders to know the URL being called and then look the web.xml to know the Servlet

Answer (score 1):

GWT forces model called Model View Presenter. [This article](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) should help.